# Clean Debian v9 install - How to change the console font to the old one of Debian v8?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, fonts

I've just got Debian 9.2.1 (w/o GUI) installed on a virtual machine from the CD iso.
The first thing I've noticed using bash was the font.

I already looked up the console-setup file as the one I found after applying my google skills to that problem, but the files on both my old Debian VM and my new one look the same.

---

It used to look like this as the default font setting in Debian v8
https://postimg.org/image/6w6mhq2s9n/

and the new default font is this bold one.
https://postimg.org/image/9dv535ajor/

---

I prefer the first one. What conf files are responsible for the fonts in Debian and what are the correct settings to get that old font back?

Comment: A crucial bit of information is missing: are you talking about the font you see in some *terminal emulator* (such as Terminal in GNOME) or about the "real console"—that is, so-called virtual terminal you see when either running w/o the X server or after switching to it from the X server by hitting, say, `Ctrl-Alt-F1`?

Comment: And if this happens in a graphical desktop environment (that is, you're running `nano` in a terminal emulator program), then what is that environment you have installed—the default one (GNOME 3) or something else?

Comment: I'm talking about the "real console". There is no GUI installed on this machine.

Comment: I think you need `dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup` (as root). Install the `console-setup` package first if it's not installed. It'll ask you about the font you'd like to use.